# When I pull the UITableView down, how can I prevent it from bouncing all the way back, instead keeping it still offset above? (Pull to refresh)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I want to implement a custom pull to refresh, and all is going well, but when I pull down and release, I want the table view (that at this point is offset to show more at the top) to not bounce back down all the way, which is the default behaviour.

Instead I want it to bounce down slightly, but not all the way, to allow the loading indicator to stay visible until the content loads.

I can't figure out how to do this without causing a stutter, or without having to remove animations all together. I've tried setting contentOffset, contentInset, `setContentOffset:animated:`, playing around with turning `bounces` on and off, I just can't make any headway.

How would I go about doing this?